# multipleOutputs error in method addNamedOutput

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use multipleOutputs like this example [here](http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2013/11/how-to-use-hadoop-multipleoutputs/)

So I have:

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "out1", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "out2", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
The method addNamedOutput(Job, String, Class<? extends OutputFormat>, 
Class<?>, Class<?>) in the type MultipleOutputs is not applicable for the 
arguments (Job, String, Class<TextOutputFormat>, Class<Text>, Class<Text>)
```

Any thougths?

Answer (score 0):

You should check which API version you are importing, there are two. You should probably use:

`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs`

instead of

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs`

In general, you want to make sure all of your imports are of one type, so either `mapred` or `mapreduce`.